# Schengen visa, multiple entry, tier 4

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a Tier 4 student, from India in the UK.

I am applying for a Schengen visa with multiple entry, but in the application I am unsure of how to respond to the 'date of departure from the Schengen area'. I have at least three trips planned in 2016:
1. France (January, 4days)
2. Malta (February, 4 days)
3. Spain (May, 4days)

I was applying to the French Embassy, since that is the port of first call. I have the flight bookings of all, and the hotel bookings for France and Malta.

Could someone help?

Comment: Use the final departure date and include your bookings as evidence of your itinerary.

Comment: @GayotFow: Even if the visits are as widely spaced as indicated here? Sounds like that will look (at least at first glance) like he's planning a visit that lasts for more than 90 days ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes it will, I agree; but they are clever enough to examine the itinerary and see what the OP's intentions are.  The departure date for this type of thing is the last day the applicant will be in the zone.