# UK tourist visa application

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

My wife and I got a UK standard visitor visa, valid from 31 Aug 2016 until 28 Feb 2017. We were in the UK from 20 December and left on 6 Jan 2017. I am planning to visit again in May and I want to apply in February before my current visa expires on 28 February. What should I answer to the question of whether I am traveling with anyone on the visa held (yes or no)?

Comment: Are you planning on travelling with anyone?

Comment: Why would you think that the obvious answer is not the right one?

Answer (score 8):

You have a Standard Visitor Visa that expires on 28 Feb 2017 and you want to make a fresh application at that time. Your wife also has a Standard Visitor Visa.

You want to know what to fill in for the form question that asks if you are travelling with someone.

First you inspect your itinerary and determine if another person (in particular your wife) will be accompanying you. You may have to consult with her as part of that.

If the answer to that question is 'yes', then fill in your wife's details. Otherwise if you are not travelling with someone you should leave it blank and proceed to the next question.

Comment: Concerning applying for a new visa with an unexpired visa of the same classification in your passport, is there not a rule about it which I read a couple of days ago?

Comment: I'm cracking up here. I found the posting. It was ans answer written by you however **SPECIFICALLY** applicable to Schengen visa renewals so not applicable in this case.. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87734/how-does-schengen-multiple-entry-visa-work/87735#87735